# Swift encode url to windowsCP1251 adding percent encoding

Tags: swift, string, encode

I have server requirements to use windowsCP1251 encoding in URL requests. The legacy code on Objective-C uses CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes that is deprecated.

I can use

```
mySting.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.windowsCP1251)
```

but it is deprecated. And if I use

```
str.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

it gives me wrong results, because this method uses default UTF8 encoding.

For example I have this code

```
let mySting = "Задача"

//use deprecated method but return correct result
let correctResult = mySting.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.windowsCP1251)
//returns "%C7%E0%E4%E0%F7%E0"   , that's correct

//uses recommended method but returns incorrect result
let incorrectResult = mySting.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
//returns "%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0", that's incorrect
```

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42899730/6541007). I think the method `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:using:)` in the extension would work for CP1251.